# Performing PCA on a large dataset

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've got a document classification problem with only 2 classes and my training dataset matrix size, after the CountVectorizer becomes (40,845 X 218,904) (unigram). In the case of considering trigrams, it can reach up to (40845 X 3,931,789). Is there a way to perform PCA on such dataset without getting memory or sparse dataset errors. I'm using python sklearn on an 6GB machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've got 6GB RAM you've got a 64bit machine, so the easiest solution is probably to just up your RAM.

Otherwise, crosspost of this: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-calculate-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-general-matrix/7487#7487

There has been some good research on this recently. The new approaches use "randomized algorithms" which only require a few reads of your matrix to get good accuracy on the largest eigenvalues. This is in contrast to power iterations which require several matrix-vector multiplications to reach high accuracy.

You can read more about the new research here:

http://math.berkeley.edu/~strain/273.F10/martinsson.tygert.rokhlin.randomized.decomposition.pdf

http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4061

This code will do it for you:

http://cims.nyu.edu/~tygert/software.html

https://bitbucket.org/rcompton/pca_hgdp/raw/be45a1d9a7077b60219f7017af0130c7f43d7b52/pca.m

http://code.google.com/p/redsvd/

https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/stochastic-singular-value-decomposition.html

If your language of choice isn't in there you can roll your own randomized SVD pretty easily; it only requires a matrix vector multiplication followed by a call to an off-the-shelf SVD.

Comment: scikit-learn actually does a randomized SVD. The problem is in the centering of the matrix, which is not doable for large sparse matrices.

Comment: Mahout has to deal with the centering problem as well. The SSVD docs describe how they handle it: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/27832158/SSVD-CLI.pdf?version=18&modificationDate=1381347063000

Comment: That's a very interesting document, but it doesn't describe how they do the implicit mean-centering in the SSVD routine (only the decomposition of unseen data transformation is explained). Any idea how the SVD is done?

Comment: Page 4 addresses the mean-centering. You're right that they don't explain the storage issue. For SSVD, one only needs to apply A-\Xi to a few random vectors. Since \Xi is rank-1, it can be stored/applied cheaply as \xi^T*1. So the trick is to apply A and \xi^T*1 and then subtract. Remark: I have not actually looked into the code but I'm pretty sure this is what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

You could try sparse SVD instead, as implemented through TruncatedSVD in sklearn:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html

Performing SVD on a document dataset is a common technique, usually referred to as Latent Semantic Analysis (LSA). SVD and PCA are also quite similar. If you would like to know more about the differences, this question has some good information:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/what-is-the-intuitive-relationship-between-svd-and-pca

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need too many components (which you normally don't), you can compute the principal components [iteratively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Iterative_computation). I've always found this to be sufficient in practice.