# Can sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD be applied to a matrix in parts?

Tags: python, matrix, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svd

I am applying sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD to very large matrices. If the matrix is above a certain size (say 350k by 25k), svd.fit(x) runs out of RAM.

I am applying svd to feature matrices, where each row represents a set of features extracted from a single image.

To work around the memory issues, is it safe to apply svd to parts of the matrix (and then concatenate)?

**Will the result be the same?** I.e.:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=128)
part_1 = svd.fit_transform(features[0:100000, :])
part_2 = svd.fit_transform(features[100000:, :])
svd_features = np.concatenate((part_1, part_2), axis=0)
```

.. equivalent to(?):

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=128)
svd_features = svd.fit_transform(svd_features)
```

---

If not, is there a workaround for dim reduction of very large matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results will not be the same,

For example, consider the code below:

```
import numpy as np
features=np.array([[3, 2, 1, 3, 1],
       [2, 0, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 3, 2, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 3, 2, 3],
       [1, 1, 2, 1, 3]])
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2)
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2)
part_1 = svd.fit_transform(features[0:2, :])
part_2 = svd.fit_transform(features[2:, :])
svd_features = np.concatenate((part_1, part_2), axis=0)
svd_b = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2)
svd_features_b = svd_b.fit_transform(features)
print(svd_features)
print(svd_features_b)
```

This prints

```
[[ 4.81379561 -0.90959982]
 [ 3.36212985  1.30233746]
 [ 4.70088886  1.37354278]
 [ 4.76960857 -1.06524658]
 [ 3.94551566 -0.34876626]]


[[ 4.17420185  2.47515867]
 [ 3.23525763  0.9479915 ]
 [ 4.53499272 -1.13912762]
 [ 4.69967028 -0.89231578]
 [ 3.81909069 -1.05765576]]
```

which are different from each other.

Comment: @ChrisParry You may check if there is something relevant here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450051/performing-pca-on-a-large-dataset

Comment: Thank you, I have been trying the "arpack" algo, but I think "randomized" may work within the memory limitation.